# To delete a row dynamically from a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help in deleting the row one by one from the bottom of the table on clicking the delete row button.

**Issue:**

I have used the javascript function to delete a row from my table, instead of deleting the row one by one from the bottom it is getting deleted as a whole except the first 2 rows. I need to delete the rows from the bottom one by one except the first 2 rows when the delete button is clicked .

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;

                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {

            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                    if(rowCount <= 2) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

      <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <br/>
    <br/>

     <table id="dataTable" align="center" width="350px" border="1">

   <tr>
         <th> Product Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
         <th> Brand</th>       

    </tr>

    <tr>

   <td> <input type="text" name="pname"/></td> &nbsp;
   <td><input type="text" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><select name="brand"/>
    <option value="select">SELECT</option>
  </select>
    </td>



  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this help you :

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {

    try {

       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

       var rowDelete = table.rows.length - 1;

       if (rowDelete > 1)

           table.deleteRow(rowDelete);

       else

         alert("Cannot delete all the rows.")
    }

    catch(e) {

        alert(e);
    }
}
```

final code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;

                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }

       function deleteRow(tableID) {

        try {

           var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

           var rowDelete = table.rows.length - 1;

           if (rowDelete > 1)

               table.deleteRow(rowDelete);

           else

             alert("Cannot delete all the rows.")
        }

        catch(e) {

            alert(e);
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

      <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <br/>
    <br/>

     <table id="dataTable" align="center" width="350px" border="1">

   <tr>
         <th> Product Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
         <th> Brand</th>       

    </tr>

    <tr>

   <td> <input type="text" name="pname" value="" /></td> &nbsp;
   <td><input type="text" name="qty" value=""/></td>
    <td><select name="brand"/>
        <select>
           <option value="select">SELECT</option>

       </select>
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the loop deleting the rows, you should check first the number of rows. or you can remove the loop since you are just deleting one row only which is the last row **(rowCount-1)**;

Try this:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {

            try {
                    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                    if (rowCount > 2){

                        //for(var i =1; i < 2; i++) {
                        //  var row = table.rows[i];
                              table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);

                         //}
                    }
                    else{
                     alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    }

             }
             catch(e) {
                alert(e);
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, you didnt break the execution after deleting a row, thats why it was deleting all the rows

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {

            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                    if(rowCount <= 2) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this Helps :

```
$('#tbl1').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})

$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('#tbl1').append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="txtBox" /></td><td><input type="button" value="X" /></td></tr>')
});
```

Here is something to work with an HTML Snippet

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" style="border: 1px solid blue">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txtBox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="X" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Add">
</p>
```